# Specs2 Tests Fail to Run Natively in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, specs2

Running Specs2 in IntelliJ fails.  Running the same tests manually via an SBT task works just fine without any problems.

- **Message**: "Test framework quit unexpectedly"
- **IntelliJ**: v.15.0.5 or 2016.2 EAP (build #IC-162.426.1)
- **Platform**: Scala 2.11.7, SBT 0.13.8, Specs2 2.4.17, Play! 2.3.10

This is a common error response, but it looks like the root cause is different for a lot of other people.  I have troubleshoot this issue before and corrected it by adding the following to `build.sbt`:

```
fork in Test := false
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

Now the tests are failing again.  I have looked through the revision history of our `build.sbt` file but I do not notice anything significant that would instigate such a regression and I have no clues.

Upon step-debugging the crash I have found the following root cause:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.createInstanceFor(Classes.scala:154)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.createInstanceFor(Classes.scala:207)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$createInstanceOfEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:145)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$createInstanceOfEither$1.apply(Classes.scala:145)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.createInstanceOfEither(Classes.scala:145)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.createInstanceOfEither(Classes.scala:207)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.org$specs2$reflect$Classes$$createInstanceForConstructor(Classes.scala:118)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$4.apply(Classes.scala:98)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$$anonfun$4.apply(Classes.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:98)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:207)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:70)
    at org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObject(Classes.scala:207)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationFromClassOrObject(BaseSpecification.scala:126)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationOption(BaseSpecification.scala:107)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecification(BaseSpecification.scala:95)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.createSpecification(ClassRunner.scala:60)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.start(ClassRunner.scala:31)
    at org.specs2.runner.NotifierRunner.start(NotifierRunner.scala:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSpecs2_old(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSingleTest(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:204)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.main(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Tree, but interface was expected
    at org.specs2.mutable.SideEffectingCreationPaths$class.$init$(FragmentsBuilder.scala:245)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.<init>(Specification.scala:12)
    at controllers.VerificationApiSpec.<init>(VerificationApiSpec.scala:26)
    ... 32 more
```

`scalaz.Tree` is a transitive dependency of many other dependencies in my project that request versions including `7.1.1`, `7.1.2`, `7.1.3`, `7.0.6` of `scalaz`.  It's interesting to note that in `7.0.x` `scalaz.Tree` is a trait (interface in Java vernacular) but an abstract class in `7.1.x`, so this may constitute the root cause.

Is it possible to resolve this issue given the transitive dependency conflicts with scalaz `7.1.x` and `7.0.x` which are evidentially incompatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specs2 `2.4.17` uses Scalaz `7.1.0`. Some other dependency in your build is probably dragging a Scalaz `7.2.x` dependency. I suggest that you update your `specs2` version to `3.8.4` which will bring a more recent version of Scalaz in scope.

Comment: I think you are right, I updated my question to reflect this.  I will try upgrading to 3.8.4 but barring that is it possible to resolve such a transitive dependency conflict?

Comment: Since your project is working fine with sbt I suggest that you drop the wrong jars from your module dependencies in Intellij.